# How can I bind a view-model property to a dynamic resource in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dynamicresource

I use dynamic resources for localization in my application. It works as expected if I name a resource directly.

```
<Button Content="{DynamicResource Home}"
              Command="{Binding NavigateHomeCommand}"
              Margin="30 0"/>
```

Still templates localization needs bindings for view-model properties which seem to be incompatible with dynamic resources.
Here's the code example.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type presentation:SideBarItem}"
                  x:Key="OptionsButtonTemplate">
      <Button Command="{Binding NavigateRelatedViewCommand}">
        <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource {Binding Title}}"
                       FontSize="18"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
      </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Is there a workaround for this case?

Comment: You could use a markup extension. Pass the resource id in as a property and use tryfindresource on that.

Comment: It worked!
But isn't there a more straight-forward solution?

Comment: Do you know that WPF already provides the infrastructure for localization? If want to set UI values via data binding instead, you should localize the data of the binding source. The binding source should expose localized data to the view. But it's more convenient to localize the UI from XAML the way WPF provides you for example using the x:Uid directive on XAML elements.